# libGDX stop animation at last frame

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, 2d

I have class which extends Actor. My animations are in 'act' method with stateTime timer. Below is fragment of this class:

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    stateTime += delta;

    if(!isDeath) {

       ...

    } else {
        if(!animationDead.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){
            textureRegion = animationDead.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        }

    }
}
```

animationDead has PLAYMODE.NORMAL

I'm trying to use '!animationDead.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)' but it's stoping my animation after first frame. I would like to stop animation after last frame.

Also i'm trying to set stateTime = 0; but the same, stopping after first frame.

The same situation i have when i press for example SPACE key my 'actor' should play fight animation. But for all frames of fight animaton i have to hold space key. One tap space is one frame of animation.

Here is fragment of this method:

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    stateTime += delta;

    if(!isAttacking()) {
    ...

    /* Keyboard events */
    ...
    setAttacking(false);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
        setAttacking(true);
        if (moveToRight) {
            textureRegion = animationAttack.getKeyFrame(stateTime,true);
        } else if (!moveToRight) {
            isPlayerFlippedToLeft = true;
            textureRegion = animationAttack.getKeyFrame(stateTime,true);
        }
        setPlayerWidthAndHeight();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your call `animationDead.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);` method on Animation then `Animation's` mode is converted into `PlayMode.LOOP` or  `PlayMode.LOOP_REVERSED` depending upon what's animation mode current have.

`PlayMode.NORMAL` -> `PlayMode.LOOP`

`PlayMode.REVERSED` -> `PlayMode.LOOP_REVERSED`

`isAnimationFinished(stateTime)` return true if the animation would be finished if **played without looping**.

Why don't you call `animationAttack.getKeyFrame(stateTime);`

**EDIT**

Ok, now you're using `animationAttack.getKeyFrame(stateTime);`

You're using same `stateTime` for three different `Animation`, when time comes to show animation of `animationDead`, `stateTime` crossed animation `frameduration` and at that time `isAnimationFinished(stateTime)` return true so

```
if(!animationDead.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){  //condition false
   textureRegion = animationDead.getKeyFrame(stateTime); 
}
```

finally textureRegion having no dead `TextureRegion` frame.

Comment: When i call `animationAttack.getKeyFrame(stateTime);` i see only first or last (i'm nor sure) but only one frame of animation and animation is stopped @Abhishek Aryan

Comment: because it runs once if your Animation mode is `PlayMode.NORMAL`. make your animation slow, so that you can see all frames

Comment: slowing down animation doesn't solve problem @Abhishek Aryan

Comment: here is full code https://github.com/twistezo/ninja-vs-zombie/blob/master/core/src/com/twistezo/characters/ZombieFemale.java  i think the problem is somewhere in skeleton of this act method

Comment: `isAnimationFinished(stateTime)`return true if the animation would be finished if **played without looping**.

Comment: so now i have like this `} else if (isDeath){ if(!animationDead.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){ textureRegion = animationDead.getKeyFrame(stateTime); } }` it's without looping and like i said i see only one frame and animation is stopping. When i slow down animation it's the same @Abhishek Aryan